# How to execute a server side script when contact form 7 is submitted?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I am new to wordpress and I am trying to create a simple form. I am currently using contact form 7 and so far it find it nice. But now, I am trying to execute a server side code when the form is submitted. Basically, what I just want is to get the post variables from the from when it is submitted so that I can use the form data in the script. I still want the email functionality that sends to the email address when the form is submitted.

Is there a simple and more efficient way to do it without me need to change anything in the code?

Comment: Define "server side script"? Are you talking about PHP that can run in a WordPress context? A bash/Perl/other script? What? And what does the script need to do?

Answer (score 8):

You need `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook that gets triggered after sending email successfully.
Just add this in your `functions.php`.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'process_contact_form_data' );
function process_contact_form_data( $contact_data ){

    var_dump($contact_data->posted_data);
            $name = $contact_data->posted_data["your-name"];
    $email = $contact_data->posted_data["your-email"];

    echo $name ;
    echo $email;                
}
```

You can access fields by their name in `$contact_data->posted_data` array.

---

Yes. You can redirect to another page either with javascript or from above function. With javascript you need to add following line in **Additional Settings** of contact form you've created.

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://youdomain.com/thankyou.php';"
```

But this won't allow you to use values sent from form. So go for alternate method.

Redirect to *thankyou* page from above mentioned function. But before redirecting, set information you want to show on *thankyou* page into **SESSION** variables ( like name, email, subject fields from form ). Then on *thankyou* page, get those values and display them. Later you can destory session variables and check everytime if those certain variables are set. This will give control over hitting *thankyou* url directly from browser and show appropriate message saying page is not directly accessible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Phobos. Is it possible that when the form has been submitted then I will redirect to something like a thank you page wherein I could use the post variables from the form that was just submitted from contact 7?

Comment: @drifter please check updated answer.

Comment: this doesn't work. apart from not redirecting, the user gets no feedback from the form submission (despite the e-mail being sent) and is stuck with and endless loading animation. By the way, the authors officially discourage using the `on_sent_ok` hook (which actually works) and provide a [solution](https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/) that unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: As it’s been long time author may have changed the api and hooks.

Comment: `on_sent_ok` is deprecated and not available

Comment: DOESN'T WORK ANYMORE, the datas should now be processed using `$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();` and `$posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59547649/2498324)